# Is it possible to dismiss in one go, all Web Browser notifications in Microsoft Edge web browser?

Tags: microsoft-edge, notifications

I am usually working on one computer but I sometimes switch to another.  On the 2nd one, I enabled Web notifications from the instant messaging website Slack, in MS-Edge, since I don't want to miss a potentially time-sensitive message.

The problem is that if I haven't been on that machine for a while, when I eventually get to it, there could be dozens (or even hundreds) notifications displayed on the screen, and each needs to be dismissed with a click (they do time out after a while, but then the next "pending" batch is displayed, and meanwhile they obscure a part of the screen).

Is there a way to dismiss all the received notifications all at once?  Closing and reopening the browser does not work.

**Clarification:** The question is unrelated to Slack, I used Slack as an example for why turning Web notifications off is not a good solution for me.

I found this [**site**](https://www.bennish.net/web-notifications.html) that allows testing notifications.  Click "Authorize", then click "Show" some 20 times.  I am asking for a way to batch-dismiss all of them.

Comment: This [Slack article](https://www.fastcompany.com/3068379/five-slack-hacks-that-can-keep-you-productive-no-matter-what) has these shortcuts: "Clear unread messages in a channel: Esc; Clear all unread messages: Shift+Esc". Does this help?

Comment: If you open the notification center from the corner button, you can clear all notifications at once for a specific application (edge) by clicking the X on that app's header

Comment: @Cpt.Whale, those are browser notifications, they do not appear in the OS notification center.

Comment: @harrymc, I don't want to mark all messages as read in Slack, I want to clear the *browser* Web notifications.  I'll edit the question to make it more clear.